# How to put text and avoid overlaps in this map?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

I want to show my position with button locate on the map but the layout that I have now overlays the text on the map, is there another way to prevent this from happening and can show the map correctly without getting below information that I have on the top?.

The map should start after the white frame.
[image]

Full code Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MapActivity" >

    <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="10dp">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/magTxt"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/richterTxt"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/magTxt"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/richterTxt"
        android:gravity="center"/>        

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tituloLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/magTxt"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/tituloLabel" />    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tituloTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tituloLabel"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profundidadLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/magTxt"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/profundidadLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tituloLabel" />    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/depthTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profundidadLabel"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tituloTxt"
        />
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kmLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/depthTxt"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tituloTxt"
        android:text="@string/kmLabel"
        android:textSize="16sp"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fechaTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/magTxt"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profundidadLabel"
        />  

    </RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you provide the full .xml with the Button on it?

Comment: @NSimon the button is the element part of the map map.setMyLocationEnabled(true). I updated the image. The map should start after the white frame.

Comment: Then just reorder your xml so that you got the RelativeLayout (give it an id) on top, and the fragment below with tag `android:layout_below="@id/RelativeLayoutId"`

Comment: Was a pleasure to help!